# Does the angular momentum of a Black Hole give insight into a potential solution for the singularity?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, angular-momentum, event-horizon, singularities

Alright so, i want to make one thing clear. I am a bit of a dumbass who watches a lot of PBS Spacetime and read a paper or to on visualising Black Holes. Example image (10k):

[image]

I asked a very similar question, well the same one, a while ago but the way i asked was kind of trash. So this is attempt Nr. 2.

As far as i understand it, in Physics most people agree that a Black Hole probably does not contain an actual Singularity at its center. As in a single point with infinit density and zero volume. This is because usually when we encounter infinities in our theories it is a sign that something is wrong.

We observe Black Holes with spin´s all the way to 0.99c. Crucially, there are Black Holes with spin´s of 0.8c and similar. So there is clearly a range. Not all Black Holes spin with the same velocity.
And i would argue, if Black Holes actually collapsed into infinitly small points, all Black Holes should have the same Spin of 1 or nearly c.

Lemme explain, Angular momentum is given by $L = mvr$ where $m$ is the mass, $v$ is the velocity and $r$ is the radius. Whatever the Black Hole was originally made off, it had a Angular momentum. So duo to the conservation of Angular momentum, when the Black Hole was created and the Radius became a lot smaller it spun a lot faster. If a Black Hole would actually have a singularity at its center, $r$ would be 0 and Angular Velocity would be infinit Which in this case would be $c$.

But we dont observe this, instead a range of differnt spin´s is observed. So does the fact that we observe any spin under $c$ at all not automatically rule out the possibility of a singularity ?

A counter to this may be that all the infalling matter creating the Black Hole averages out the angular momentum. But this line of thought does not work as $r$ is said to be 0. So even if the angular velocity was 1nm/s, the final spin should still be infinit.

With all of this, should it not be possible to use the angular momentum of any new Black Hole to calculate the Radius of whatever is at the center ? Like, imagine this scenario. We through the means of bad sci fi manage to build a machine that can compress Matter into a Black Hole. We go to Mercury and do exactly that. Before Mercury gets $compactified$ we messure its exact Mass and angular velocity. This gives us figures $m1$, $v1$ and $r$. After it got promoted to Black Hole we take the same messurements gaining $m2$ and $v2$. We should see that $m1 > m2$ and $v2 >>> v1$ are true. Since we knew the Original Radius of Mercury, it is possible to use $v2$, $m2$ and $r1$ to get a figure for how small the Radius of the Core has to be to get this new velocity. In fact this should be the exact same Math used to calculate the new Radius of say a ballerina after she pulled her arms together. IF you know the original velocity, original Radius, and the new velocity you can get that number.

And this $r$ should correspond to the equator radius of the "core" of the Black Hole.

Now this does raise a few questions. Like what force manages to halt the endless implosion of Mercury dead in its tracks. Or why it not imidiatly rebounds similar to how a Supernova works when it´s implosion is halted.

Those are nice questions and i am nowhere near smart enough to answer them. In fact i kind of expect someone to point out a really obvious reason why my line of thinking here is not correct. But i have been thinking about it, and i dont see it.

Comment: There's a nice chart of SMBH spins at the end of this excellent answer on our sister site: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/20292/16685

Comment: There are a few problems with your proposed experiment. The Schwarzschild radius of Mercury is slightly over 0.49 mm. OTOH, your planet crusher will add energy (and hence mass) to Mercury. How do you crush it without changing its angular momentum?

Comment: Its a thought experiment @PM2Ring. I am aware we could not do this in reality, but it is more about there being a process which theoretically could give insight into the center. I guess the TLDR is that i dont see how Black Holes are supposed to be singularities if conservation of Angular momentum is not violated.

Comment: @PM2Ring Why though ? We could just use Magic for all it matters. The point is more a theoretical one. As in lets say we could. If you say it needs Energy to implode Mercury, thats true but where is that an issue ? We odd to know how much energy we put in ?

Comment: @PM2Ring hold the phone, how do Black Holes grow then ? I am aware of the fact that we cant observe anything falling into a Black Hole, as it would get Redshifted to infinit. But even then, does that really matter ? If we just assume it is possible to implode Mercury and messure the energy we put in, shouldnt the process outline above for "messuring" the center still work ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135822/discussion-between-theblender-and-pm-2ring).